# How to use textfield key press event using python

Tags: python, tkinter

if i write some thing on the textfield and press enter key on the keyboard.what i entered on the textfield display messagebox. this point get error  if(format(k=event.char(13)))) : if i set the enter key code. i added full code below.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("800x800")
global e1

def callback(event):
    if(format(k=event.char(13)))):
           
    msg = e1.get()
    
    print(msg)


Label(root, text="Student Name").place(x=140, y=40)

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x=140, y=10)
e1.bind('<Key>',callback)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what do you indent to do with `if(format(k=event.char(13)))):`

Comment: i jst put with 13 number mean enter key number

Comment: if i press enter key what write on the textfield display the message

Comment: any mistake here

Comment: Ive added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")

def callback(event):           
    msg = e1.get()
    print(msg)

Label(root, text="Student Name").place(x=140, y=40)

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x=140, y=10)
e1.bind('<Return>',callback) #<Return> is equivalent to your Enter key

root.mainloop()
```

When you click on Enter key, on the entry widget, then the function gets called and the output will be printed out. I also removed the `global` as it makes no sense to use it in outside functions.

Hope it helped you out.

Cheers

Comment: i asked the question about printing recept on terminal printer python i added the question and pass into you now

Comment: @tutsfun Actually, i didnt see any questions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752726/print-the-receipt-on-thermal-printer-python  here is question please check