# print the receipt on thermal printer python

Tags: python, tkinter

i am creating a inventory system on python.i need genterating print recipt after all sales done.when i click save button.i have using mysql database. it has sales and sales product table
sales tables consist of following colums – id,subtotal,pay,balance.
sales_products tables consist of following colums –id,sales_id,item,qty,price,total need to save the data into two diffent tables when i hit save button at the same time print recipt should display.i don't know to how to save the data on multipule tables i  don't know how to save all the treeview save on the database . i got lastinsert id below in the save function.

[image]

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

import mysql.connector

def save():
    totall = float(tot.cget("text"))
    pay = float(e11.get())
    bal = pay - totall

    mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="milkshop")
    mycursor = mysqldb.cursor()

    try:
        sql = "INSERT INTO sales (id,subtotal,pay,balance) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = ("", totall, pay, bal)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        mysqldb.commit()
        lastid = mycursor.lastrowid


    except Exception as e:

        print(e)
        mysqldb.rollback()
        mysqldb.close()

def pay():
    totall = float(tot.cget("text"))
    pay = float(e11.get())
    bal = pay - totall
    balText.set(bal)

root = Tk()
root.title("Inventory System using Python")
root.geometry("1000x600")
global e1
global e2
global e3
global e4
global totText
global balText

totText = StringVar()
balText = IntVar()

Label(root, text="Inventory System using Python", font="arial 22 bold").place(x=5, y=10)

var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Thai Fried Rice", variable=var1).place(x=10, y=50)

var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Basil Fried Rice", variable=var2).place(x=10, y=80)

var3 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Pineapple Fried Rice", variable=var3).place(x=10, y=110)

var4 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Crab Fried Rice", variable=var4).place(x=10, y=140)

var5 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text=" Fish Fried Rice  ", variable=var5).place(x=10, y=170)
Label(root, text="Total").place(x=600, y=10)

Label(root, text="Pay").place(x=600, y=50)
Label(root, text="Balance").place(x=600, y=80)


e8 = Entry(root)
e8.place(x=300, y=110)

e9 = Entry(root)
e9.place(x=300, y=140)

e10 = Entry(root)
e10.place(x=300, y=170)

tot = Label(root, text="", font="arial 22 bold", textvariable=totText)
tot.place(x=650, y=10)

e11 = Entry(root)
e11.place(x=650, y=50)

e12 = Entry(root)

balance = Label(root, text="", font="arial 22 bold", textvariable=balText).place(x=650, y=80)
Button(root, text="Add", command=show, height=3, width=13).place(x=10, y=220)
Button(root, text="PayNow", command=pay, height=3, width=13).place(x=650, y=120)
Button(root, text="Save", command=save, height=3, width=13).place(x=750, y=120)



cols = ('item', 'price', 'qty', 'total')
listBox = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=cols, show='headings')

for col in cols:
    listBox.heading(col, text=col)
    listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    listBox.place(x=10, y=300)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Its a lot of code to look into, post the area of code, that is necessary for the question.

Comment: now check i need save treeview data  treeview has item,qty,price,totall all row data data need to save then print recepit display for print

Comment: You need to print the treeview data in the terminal as a receipt right?

Comment: yes man .........................

Comment: treeview data need to save on the mysql database too.

Comment: your title says _"print the receipt on thermal printer python"_ what does thermal mean?

Comment: thermal mean the pos system printer it used in shops. no need the thermal  i need print recipt only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221009/discussion-between-tuts-fun-and-cool-cloud).

Comment: Im sorry, im not sure on how to do this, but if you want, i can get you a template of reciept and maybe you can add the values yourself?

Comment: ok ..........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i think you should proceed with the reciept.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def reciept():
    top = Toplevel()
    price1 = 3000
    qty1 = 3
    total1 = price1*qty1

    price2 = 5000
    qty2 = 4
    total2 = price1*qty2

    l = Label(top,text='---------RECIEPT----------')
    l.pack()
    heading = Label(top,text='PRICE\tQTY\tTOTAL')
    heading.pack()

    item1 = Label(top,text=f'{price1}\t{qty1}\t{total1}')
    item1.pack()

    item2 = Label(top,text=f'{price2}\t{qty2}\t{total2}')
    item2.pack()

b = Button(root,text='Print reciept',command=reciept)
b.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

The `\t` will add 4 spaces to the end of the letter.

You can replace prices with your `e1.get()` and all.

You can also use `grid()` here but it might be cumbersome and takes more lines.

[Check here on how to print using python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Z_Mj-AMrdo)

Hope you got an idea.

Cheers

Comment: ya this i need to print on GUI  tkinter

Comment: get the print recipt for print

Comment: ya good thanks . shall i print button and print the recipt

Comment: when  i see the print view automattly on the printer print i asked

Comment: Im not sure on how to get this to be printed on your printer, maybe ask a new Q or google it.

Comment: Ive updated the answer, with some links. Would appreciate if you could mark this as the answer

Comment: thanks. i have a another question.thats treeview all data how to save on the mysql database

Comment: Im not sure, if ill have an answer, anyway try asking it